# How to give database id as many2one field in odoo load method

Tags: python, odoo-10

I'm trying to create records(category, products ...) in bulk using load orm method in odoo v10.

The problem I'm having is about how to reference m2o field as database id.

```
# get list of categ name from input data
parent_categ_codes = [categ['name'] for categ in categ_data]
# get product.category by name
parent_categ_objs = self.env['product.category'].search([('name','in',parent_categ_codes)])
parent_dict = {categ.name: categ for categ in parent_categ_objs}
data = []
fields_name = ['name', 'parent_id']
# populate data
for categ in categ_data:
# this works but very slow beacuse of name_search lookup
    data.append([categ['name'], parent_dict[categ['parent_id']].name])
self.env['product.category'].load(fields_name,data)
```

How can I just create a reference for `parent_id` as id?

`data.append([categ['name'], parent_dict[categ['parent_id']].id])` does not work

[reference link](http://odoo-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/06_misc_import.html)

thanks

Comment: thanks for corrections and sorry for grammatical mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figure it out. Just do it like

```
fields_name = ['name', 'parent_id/.id']
```

then

```
cl['ClassName'], parent_dict[cl['Deps']].id
```

will work.
 And also `fields_name = ['name', 'parent_id/id']` will for external id i.e. xml id